# Quartz compiling job scripts after runtime?

Tags: .net, vb.net, quartz.net

I want to use Quartz to act as a script scheduler, you write the VB from a GUI and then select a trigger, the code is then compiled and executed on the trigger, the difficult bit is how do I handle it so that it runs this script with in the application context so it can access my entity framework models, etc. How would I achieve this?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Quartz (I assume you mean Quartz.net), but iirc you can't inject anything but some string-data into a quartz job. The way I previously solved this was by accessing global state (via my IoC or a static variable) from the job that is executed, which felt super messy. I don't know if quartz now has DI support, but I guess it doesn't :(

Comment: @cwap Surely that would work though, the string could be some VB to execute?

Comment: It probably could, but the string will need to be able to be persisted. Depending on your quartz storage settings and the string length this could be a problem. Look into JobDataMap ( http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html ). The 'problem' is that all quartz jobs must be fully serializable into the quartz data model, so dynamic data and collections are a no-go. I guess something like a script could work, though I'd personally opt for building the script-storage somewhere else, like in a separate database or folder on the filesystem.

Comment: What exactly you want to get from Quartz? Do you want to run scripts at exact time or just pull scripts from some queue at regular interval?

Comment: @AlexeyMerson I want to easily be able to alter scripts via a GUI and then be able to bind triggers to them, in the background Quartz will run as a service to take these scripts and triggers and fire them as dictated by the trigger. These scripts and triggers would probably be picked up from my own database schema as I want to use EF which the default db schema for Quartz doesn't support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you need is to put [Quartz.Server](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/server/Quartz.Server) on top of your application. Add this project to your solution.

If you just need to use your entities in quartz jobs then add your project with entities as reference to Quartz.Server and use entities as you do in your main app.

If you use some IoC-container then you can use extensions like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf.Quartz.Ninject/) to inject dependecies to the job. Or you can write your own SchedulerFactory and JobFactory and build your job environment here.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I made some progress with this, would you please check out my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309777/accessing-local-types-from-script-executed-with-vbcodeprovider