# Accessing local types from script executed with VBCodeProvider

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using VBCodeProvider, however I would like it to be able to access types such as those from Entity Framework. Is this possible?

Here's my code...

```
Imports Quartz.Impl
Imports Quartz
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler

Module Module1

    Private factory As New StdSchedulerFactory

    Sub Main()

        Dim scheduler As IScheduler = factory.GetScheduler

        Dim trigger1 As ITrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create.
            WithIdentity("expire", "Primary").WithCronSchedule("*/5 * * * * ?").Build

        Dim executeScript As IJobDetail = JobBuilder.
            Create.OfType(Of ExecuteScript).
            UsingJobData("Script", My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("ExampleScript.vb")).
            Build

        With scheduler
            .ScheduleJob(executeScript, trigger1)
            .Start()
        End With

    End Sub

End Module

Class ExecuteScript
    Implements IJob

    Public Sub Execute(context As IJobExecutionContext) Implements IJob.Execute
        Dim dataMap As JobDataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap
        Using codeProvider As New VBCodeProvider
            Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters With {
                .GenerateInMemory = True,
                .TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
            }
            Dim results As CompilerResults = codeProvider.
                CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, dataMap("Script"))
            If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR")
                For Each e As CompilerError In results.Errors
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorText)
                Next
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

The file 'ExampleScript.vb' contains a script with references to types inside of my project, however I am unable to use these as it seems there's separation between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all necessary references to the compiler. Assuming one of your entity is called `SomeEntity` you need to do the following before compiling:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(GetType(SomeEntity).Assembly.Location)
```

Comment: Also look [here](http://www.csscript.net) if you need to compile C# code.

Comment: Hi Alexey, this nearly works. But it points to an executable and still throws the same errors. RESOLVED THIS ISSUE. Thanks!

Comment: Did you put usings (Imports in VB) in your script?